# C#-Roslyn:SyntaxNode is converted to FieldDeclarationSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a field SyntaxNode:

```
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = source.Token;
            SyntaxNode root = await CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("int i= 0;").GetRootAsync(token);
```

I see the documentation:

```
Inheritance->Object->SyntaxNode->
CSharpSyntaxNode->
MemberDeclarationSyntax->BaseFieldDeclarationSyntax->FieldDeclarationSyntax
```

I have ClassDeclarationSyntax :

```
private ClassDeclarationSyntax _classDeclaration;
```

I want to transform SyntaxNode into FieldDeclarationSyntax, and then add to ClassDeclarationSyntax.

How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do what you want with something like this:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Linq;

VariableDeclarationSyntax variableDeclaration = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("int i= 0;")
    .GetRoot()
    .DescendantNodes()
    .OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>()
    .Single();

_classDeclaration = _classDeclaration
    .WithMembers(
        SyntaxFactory.SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
            SyntaxFactory.FieldDeclaration(variableDeclaration)));
```

you first need to create the variable declaration syntax via parsing. then descent the root node to retrieve it. Then attach that node to a new FieldDeclaration. Though I am curious what you are trying to do here. There is the [SyntaxRewriter](https://joshvarty.com/2014/08/15/learn-roslyn-now-part-5-csharpsyntaxrewriter/) type if you want help changing the code of a tree. There is also the general codefix infrastucture and [SyntaxEditor](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/Editing/SyntaxEditor.cs) under the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing namespace.